# Moving Pivotviewer Collections from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, pivotviewer, cxml-collectionxml

I'm just playing around with PivotViewer control in Silverlight 5. It seems like many things got improved, but I'm having some issues displaying my old `.cxml` collections that perfectly worked under Silverlight 4

The old way to code:

```
InitializeComponent();
MainPivotViewer.LoadCollection("http://localhost:4573/ClientBin/Actresses.cxml",              string.Empty);
```

translates now to something like:

```
InitializeComponent();
CxmlCollectionSource _cxml = new CxmlCollectionSource(new Uri("http://localhost:1541/ClientBin/Actresses.cxml", UriKind.Absolute));
PivotMainPage.PivotProperties = _cxml.ItemProperties.ToList();
PivotMainPage.ItemTemplates = _cxml.ItemTemplates;
PivotMainPage.ItemsSource = _cxml.Items;
```

What happens is that Items are shown, but nothing shows up in the filter pane and, if an item is selected, there is no longer any description for them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that `_cxml.ItemsProperties` is not loaded until after the `CxmlCollectionSource` downloads and processes the `.cxml` file.  `CxmlCollectionSource` has a `StateChanged` event.  If you check to see if the `State` is `Loaded`, then you can map the `_cxml` properties to the PivotViewer.

Here is a sample of what this would look like:

```
        private CxmlCollectionSource _cxml;
    void pViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _cxml = new CxmlCollectionSource(new Uri("http://myurl.com/test.cxml",
                                             UriKind.Absolute));
        _cxml.StateChanged += _cxml_StateChanged;
    }

    void _cxml_StateChanged(object sender,
                           CxmlCollectionStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewState == CxmlCollectionState.Loaded)
        {
            pViewer.PivotProperties =
                       _cxml.ItemProperties.ToList();
            pViewer.ItemTemplates =
                       _cxml.ItemTemplates;
            pViewer.ItemsSource =
                       _cxml.Items;
        }
    }
```

I have [a more in depth description of this on my blog](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/09/to-cxml-or-not-to-cxml/).